# How about encouraging the users to provide MWE before asking questions?

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, mwe

In the lights of increase in the number of questions without MWE, I was wondering how can we encourage the users to provide MWE prior to submitting the questions. Considering that in many cases these questions are asked by users who do not know about MWE and they will learn about it by the comments that they receive, I have an idea:

How about adding a fade text to the question box and asking the users to include MWE. We gave guidelines about the titles, why not doing the same for the body of the questions. Something in the lines of:

---

[image]

---

This can be applied to other stackexchange siblings like stackoverflow (mcve) as well.

Comment: This is somewhat connected to my question here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4498/recommendation-for-new-users. But it's not a duplicate, of course

Comment: If we can do that much why not plugging in a dummy TeX template so people can decide to populate? Then we can nag about deleting even the existing template.

Comment: @percusse has a really excellent idea here. It's disappointing to see that nothing has happened in this direction in the years since.

Comment: I really like this feature suggestion and it's sad to see nothing has been done with this. I have started a new discussion about a related suggestion [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7749/suggest-users-to-add-a-mwe-or-mweb-to-their-question) in the hopes of improving TeX.SE.