# Is there a way to make new users aware of the use of MWEs?

Tags: feature-request

I've just reviewed at least three questions by new users and all of them just pasted a code excerpt that wasn't compilable, or worse, included uses of macros that aren't in the LaTeX base.

This is of course not the first time I see such incomplete code examples, it seems like 80% or more of all new users think it would be fine to paste only some small code snippets.

For someone wanting to help, this behavior is incredibly annoying, because you always have to wrap extra code around to make the document compile or even have to search for what packages the user might have used and add them to the import list.

Isn't there a way to make new users, i.e. at least people who ask their first question here, aware that **all code examples should be complete documents** but only include the parts that are relevant to the problem? And it shouldn't just be a link to an FAQ thread or such, but something that really makes them stumble and pay attention.

Ideally, an automatic trigger would pop up a big red box with a warning if the user used a code block in their question to make sure it really is an MWE, perhaps with a link to [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) I guess it's not possible to add such custom hooks to only parts of the network?

Comment: I share your sentiment but as far as I can see every new user is new to this site and has to be convinced of the reasons that speak for an MWE. Some users even put the standard message on their profile, e.g. [Peter Grill](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4301/peter-grill) has a nice collection of standard messages.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. We have discussed many times on this topic. Eventually, I surrendered: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8121/101651.

Comment: Related: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7388/proposal-can-we-add-a-tutorialadmission-test-for-new-users

Comment: Related: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7749/suggest-users-to-add-a-mwe-or-mweb-to-their-question, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7733/should-we-educate-new-users-by-not-answering-until and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7780/informing-new-users-about-the-mwe

Comment: I wonder if the new Ask-A-Question Wizard from Stackoverflow (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381671/the-ask-question-wizard-is-live) will be extended to other network sites and if this could improve the current situation?

Comment: See also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4606/35864